# After 20.04 upgrade my system freezes after log in unless I use Wayland

Tags: ubuntu, dell-xps, nvidia, wayland

I was running Ubuntu 18.04 on my Dell XPS. I've just upgraded 20.04.

When it boots and gets to the new log in screen, my arrow cursor is frozen and the trackpad does nothing and so the only thing I can do is reboot.

I managed to fix this by going into the boot menu and **enabling** secure boot. I'm not sure why this would work, but the cursor now moves.

I am now able to type my password and log in to the system, however: when I do so, the cursor is again stuck on the bottom right of the desktop and won't move UNLESS I choose to log in to Ubuntu Wayland and then everything seems okay.

Can someone explain what is happening?

I believe that I have had this problem before when I first got my machine and I was told various things, but it always seemed to involve some combination of (i) turning off / on secure book and (ii) removing / adding nvidia driver.

I found [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229933/login-freeze-after-update-to-20-04) which clearly had the same problem, but there isn't a clear solution in the answers and I don't want to start experimenting and making the problem worse.

Answer (score -1):

What I think is happening is that a driver is being loaded that freezes the display, and secure boot stops the driver being loaded.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: But as I mentioned, when I DISABLE secure boot, even the log in screen freezes. At least when I have secure boot enables I can log in before the freeze happens.